# including form by user action

Tags: javascript, forms

i have a page containing a form and directs to another page (page2) asusual. Page 2 have a edit button that must include the **entire previous page into a div** in *page2*(initially it has none).How to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

[load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

function in jQuery. It loads HTML from a remote file and inject it into the DOM.

```
$("#yourdivid").load("page1.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can get the html of the page using the following...

```
var x = $("body").html();
```

You can then add that to your form.

If you don't require the entire page (the page will include the form again after all), you can change the selector in the code example to limit it to any part of the page.